# Unable to run correctly firefox portable with Selenium 3

Tags: java, selenium-firefoxdriver, selenium3

I wrote a test in JUnit to launch Firefox with Selenium 3.0.1.
But I have a problem with Firefox Portable version. With Firefox installed on my machine I have not this problem.

My test is very simple :

```
public class SeleniumTest extends FluentTest {
  WebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
  static {
    // 1) Work with native Firefox
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", ClassLoader.getSystemResource("webdriver/geckodriver_0.11.1.exe").getFile());

    // 2) Don't work when I add these 2 properties
    //        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "true");
    //        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "D:\\firefox-portable\\FirefoxPortablex64-48.0.2\\FirefoxPortable.exe");
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    System.out.println("test is executed");
  }
}
```

In the case n°2, I add the properties necessary to run Firefox portable version but the test stays lock at the step "Connecting to Marionette on localhost:52702". And anything happens.

```
1478965841203   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:45941
nov. 12, 2016 4:50:41 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFOS: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
1478965841598   mozprofile::profile INFO    Using profile path d:\Profiles\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.TisH4gXwlj3K
1478967041359   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser D:\firefox-portable\FirefoxPortablex64-48.0.2\FirefoxPortable.exe
1478967041388   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Connecting to Marionette on localhost:52702
```

But with the native Firefox, I can see the next steps and the test is executed.

```
1478967281791   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 53224
1478967283064   Marionette  INFO    startBrowser d3c2b382-5643-4149-9168-57fd36a43678
nov. 12, 2016 5:14:43 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFOS: Detected dialect: W3C
test is executed
```

Finally, I precise I want to use the Firefox portable edition to be more flexible and independant.

My env :
Jdk 8 / Selenium 3.0.1 / FluentLenium 3.0.2 / GeckoDriver 0.11.1 / Native Firefox : 49.0.2 / Firefox Portable edition : 48.0.2 and also 49.0

Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: Nobody helps me ? Any idea about my problem ?

Comment: I've got the same issue. Have you got something on this ?

Comment: Hello buzz,FF portable edition doesn't work with Selenium 3 and geckodriver.

Comment: @Jonathan is that the line from Firefox Portable?